# How do deploy a public Github project that contains secret API keys to Azure?

Tags: azure, github, open-source, api-key

I have a project which I plan to open-source at some point. Currently I keep all of my API keys in a class which is not checked in - I have just linked the project to Azure but the API key class not being present causes the deployment to fail.

> How can I hide secret API keys in a public project and still have it deploy to Azure?

I have read quite a few posts ([this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141698/version-control-and-personal-configuration-file) for instance) but cannot find a solution that allows me to do what I want - does anyone know what I should do here? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an Azure Web App, you can specify config values on the Configure tab in the portal (under "app settings"). These will override values specified in your `Web.config` file.

This means you can leave these settings out of your public repository.

For developing locally, you can put the settings in a separate XML file. To do this, update the `appSettings` in your Web.config like this:

```
<appSettings file="mysettings.xml" />
```

Then create `mysettings.xml` and put your actual settings in a new `<appSettings>` element there.

You can then add `mysettings.xml` to your `.gitignore` file so it won't be checked in to your public repository.

Azure doesn't mind that your `mysettings.xml` file doesn't exist, and will pick up the settings you specify in the portal instead.

Comment: Just trying to get my head round how to do this exactly. Do I check in Web.config (without keys), add the keys to my local repo so I can run it & make sure I don't push those Web.config changes to the public repo. In Azure specify the config values which in effect will override keys that aren't present?